# How to make an instagram-like tab?

Tags: ios, swift3, instagram

How to make an Instagram-like tab like this?

[Instagram's tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMDJR.jpg)

Do I need to make more than one `UIViewController`s or make something on one `UIViewController`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use **ESTabBarControllerExample** https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController to making that kind of custom TabbarController.First Download the ESTabbarControllerExample from github. We need to use some class letter on. Let me explain how to use step by step:

- **First Install CocoaPods**

  1 Open terminal and `cd ~ to your project directory`

  2 Run the command - `pod init`

  3 Your podfile should be use with - `pod
  "ESTabBarController-swift"` and save it

  4 And install it with command `pod install`
- **Open project file of .xcworkspace extension**

  1 In project we need to add [`Content`](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController/tree/master/ESTabBarControllerExample/ESTabBarControllerExample/Content) all swift class and [`pop.framework`](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController/tree/master/ESTabBarControllerExample/ESTabBarControllerExample/Framework)

  2 Don't add pop.framework using add File to. you must be add from Framework and add Others.

  3 In Content folder's all file `import ESTabBarController_swift`
- **StoryBord Stuff**

  1 Add navigation Controller ane also add `ExampleNavigationController` from the example code of EST demo. (You can add your own too) but make sure you set its Class of navigation custom swift class.
- **Code Stuff at AppDelegate.swift**

You need to do following code in side `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
            let tabBarController = ESTabBarController()
            tabBarController.delegate = self
            tabBarController.title = "Irregularity"
            tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "transparent")
            tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "background_dark")
            tabBarController.shouldHijackHandler = {
                tabbarController, viewController, index in
                if index == 2 {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
            tabBarController.didHijackHandler = {
                [weak tabBarController] tabbarController, viewController, index in

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                    let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a photo", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(takePhotoAction)
                    let selectFromAlbumAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Select from album", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(selectFromAlbumAction)
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                    tabBarController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

            let v1 = ExampleViewController()
            let v2 = ExampleViewController()
            let v3 = ExampleViewController()
            let v4 = ExampleViewController()
            let v5 = ExampleViewController()

            v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home_1"))
            v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Find", image: UIImage(named: "find"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "find_1"))
            v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityContentView(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "photo_verybig"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "photo_verybig"))
            v4.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Favor", image: UIImage(named: "favor"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "favor_1"))
            v5.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Me", image: UIImage(named: "me"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "me_1"))

            tabBarController.viewControllers = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]

            let navigationController = ExampleNavigationController.init(rootViewController: tabBarController)
            tabBarController.title = "Example"


        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController

        return true
```

Add Images for Tabbar items and other that you want to use for in Assets.
Hope that helps for you.

Sample Project: https://github.com/nitingohel/CustomTabCenterBig

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but it doesn't seem to be what I meant. Have you opened the image link yet? What I want to make is the tab in the red circle! Do you still have any ideas for it?